# Refresh Page PopAsync()

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a screen that captures digital signature which, when saving or returning, executes a postasync or postmodalasync when the screen returns to me does not reload. How can I make the page reload or refresh?

```
 <Grid BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" Padding="0" RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentView Margin="10,0,10,5" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="500">
                    <StackLayout Padding="5,0,5,5" BackgroundColor="White" Spacing="1">
                        <Label 
                Text="Firma Policia Que Realizo Visita"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                TextColor="Black" 
                FontSize="Large" 
                FontAttributes="Bold"

                 />

                    <Frame  HasShadow="true" 
                         Padding="8"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <signature:SignaturePadView  
                            x:Name="SignatureView" 

                            BindingContext="{Binding SignatureView}"
                            WidthRequest="280"
                        HeightRequest="300"
                            CaptionText="" 
                            CaptionTextColor="Blue" 
                            ClearText=""
                            PromptText=""
                            PromptTextColor="Green" 
                            BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" 
                            SignatureLineColor="Black" 
                            StrokeWidth="3" 
                            StrokeColor="Black" />
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
                </ContentView>


        </Grid>


        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="2" Spacing="2">
            <Button 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HeightRequest="40"                
                    Text="Guardar"
                    TextColor="{x:StaticResource WhiteColor}"
                    FontSize="Small"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    BackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource GreenButton}"
                 Clicked="Button_Clicked">

            </Button>
            <Button                  
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HeightRequest="40"                
                    Text="Limpiar"
                    TextColor="{x:StaticResource WhiteColor}"
                    FontSize="Small"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    BackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource SicoqYellowColor}"
                   Clicked="Button_Clicked_1">
            </Button>


        </StackLayout>
```

This is the viewmodel which makes the backbuttoncommand service

```
public Task RemoveLastModalFromBack(object parameter,bool animated = false)
    {
        var mainPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationView;
        if (mainPage != null)
        {
            mainPage.Navigation.PopAsync(animated);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

**This is the ViewModel which receives the signature data**

```
 private async Task BackButton()
    {

        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;



            await NavigationService.RemoveLastModalFromBack(str3);

            o


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            // await DialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Error", e.Message, "Aceptar");

        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

*The digital signature master page is digital signatures when you save or return the digital signatures page to reload*

Comment: use MessagingCenter, or a custom event, etc to notify that caller that the "second" page is closing

Comment: Hi brother, how would you implement it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: No i served brother

Comment: Do you want to reload the signature  or refresh signature page when you return signature page? Please explain your needs clearly.

Comment: He gave you an example, I enter the digital signatures screen, there are 3 frames, when I press a frame it directs me to the Digital Signature screen, I do the signature and when I click on it, it makes a popAsync that must direct me to the digital signatures screen again and in the frame show the image you just made, I have the binding source to show me the image .. That every time I make a signature update the image in the frame so I can send images by api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?
[image]

If so, you can use `MessagingCenter` to achieve that.

We can use `send` method of `MessagingCenter`, Here is my code in the Button click event of `SignaturesPage`,Use the `MessagingCenter` to send the data to the MainPage.

```
     private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //get stream of Signatures  from the pad
        Stream image = await SignaturePad.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png);
        MessagingCenter.Send<Stream>(image, "Image");
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

In the MainPage, I layout have `Image` to wait the stream from the `SignaturesPage`.

```
     <StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Frame BorderColor="Orange"
           CornerRadius="10"
           HasShadow="True">
        <Button AutomationId="Mybutton" Text="Save" x:Name="Mybutton" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="Mybutton_Clicked"/>
    </Frame>
    <Frame BorderColor="Orange"
           CornerRadius="10"
           HasShadow="True">
        <Image x:Name="MyImage" HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest="400"/>
    </Frame>


</StackLayout>
```

Here is my background code in the MainPage.

```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Stream>(this, "Image", (arg) =>
        {
            MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => arg);

        });

    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
    private  void Mybutton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Navigation.PushAsync(new SignaturesPage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey bro is super .. But it is on a different screen ... my control is in a frame I make a command to direct to the screen ... I make the signature and I give it to save I must return to the previous page where I press to direct to control ... And I do it with a popasync but it doesn't update me

Comment: Bro and I'm using view Model

Comment: Can you provide a demo about it?

Comment: How can I contact you faster

Comment: It doesn't show me the changes I make when I make a digital signature. So what it does is:
1. Enter the visit screen (Show frame with info)
2. When selecting a visit you go to the Digital Signatures screen Where there are 3 signatures
3 . There are 3 frames which must show the signature in each frame right there .. Each frame has a 1,2,3 signature screen
4 when signing, save the signature and must show it on the digital signatures screen

Mvvm must be used

Comment: You have three frames in same page? Each frame have signature view? You want save these signature. Then show it on the digital signatures screen? If you give me a GIF about your running demo, it will be clear.

Comment: Hey bro how are you? I already managed to do it the way you indicated in your example thank you very much